# Does Cargo support WebSphere Liberty?

Tags: websphere, websphere-liberty, cargo

Does [Cargo](https://codehaus-cargo.github.io/cargo/WebSphere+8.5.x.html) support [WebSphere Liberty](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/websphere-liberty/)? I find the Cargo page for WebSphere inconclusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not right now, but there is a [JIRA](https://codehaus-cargo.atlassian.net/projects/CARGO/issues/CARGO-1389?filter=allopenissues) for it and a [pull request](https://github.com/codehaus-cargo/cargo/pull/59) has been submitted so hopefully soon.